# How to change class name and id name by id using javascript?

Tags: javascript

When click on `CLICK HERE` . `id="one"` change to `id="two"` it's ok. but `class="one"` not change to `class="two"` , how can i do ?

```css
.one{
    background: red;
}

.two{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="test_fn()">
    CLICK HERE
</div>
<script>
    function test_fn(){
        document.getElementById('one').id = 'two';
        document.getElementById('one').classname = 'two';
    }
</script>
<br>
<div id="one" class="one">
    test
</div>
```

Comment: CAPITAL_N_DANGIT! as in `className`

Comment: use className, not classname

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to use the property `className`, not `classname`.

Then, you just changed the `id` of your element from `one` to `two`, so you need to select the element with the `id` `two` on your next line :

```js
function test_fn() {
  document.getElementById('one').id = 'two';
  document.getElementById('two').className = 'two';
}
```

```css
.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="test_fn()">CLICK HERE</div>

<div id="one" class="one">test</div>
```

**Edit :** You can also store the element before editing its properties :

```
function test_fn() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('one');
  elem.id = 'two';
  elem.className = 'two';
}
```

Comment: Use `+=` instead.

Comment: you should really just assign the element to a variable when you query it, instead of changing its id, then looking it up by the new id. This answer's more error prone, harder to read, slower.. pretty much everything worse. e.g. what if there was already a `#two` element in front of this one? Your second `getElementById` would return a different element, which is clearly not the intent.

Comment: If you have another `#two` element, the problem is elsewhere. Storing the element is still another solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, its working !

```
document.getElementById('two').className = 'two'; 
/*Spelling correction "classname" to className & getElementById('one') to getElementById('two') */
```

```css
.one{
  background: red;
}

.two{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="test_fn()">
CLICK HERE
</div>
<script>
function test_fn(){
 document.getElementById('one').id = 'two';
  document.getElementById('two').className = 'two';
}
</script>
<br>
<div id="one" class="one">
test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `classname` instead of `className`

Here is a working example...

```
<div onclick="test_fn()">
    CLICK HERE
</div>
<script>
    function test_fn(){
        document.getElementById('one').id = 'two';
        document.getElementById('one').className = 'two';
    }
</script>
<br>
<div id="one" class="one">
    test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change class `one` to `two`, you can try to add this on your `test_fn` function:

```
document.getElementById('one').removeClass('one').addClass('two');
```

Comment: While this post snippet may solve the question, including an explanation along with the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future who might not know the context.

Comment: Thanks. I have just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the ID of the selector between the calls. Assign the element to a variable first:

```
var foundEl = document.getElementById('one');
foundEl.id = 'two';
foundEl.className = 'two';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're querying by id one after you changed it to two. Store the element you'd like to change first in a variable and then preform changes:

```
let el = document.querySelector('one');
el.id = 'two';
el.className = 'two'
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your js code is executed `synchronously`, line by line.
So When you invoke `test_fn()` and line `document.getElementById('one').id = 'two';` is executed, the `<div id="one" class="one">` DOM element changes to `<div id="two" class="one">`.

Next, the line `document.getElementById('one').classname = 'two';` is executed but it will result in error `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` because you try to get an element with id="one" However, this time cannot find it because you previously changed it id="two" ;-P